# Are "Selective Extra Dimensions" possible?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, spacetime-dimensions, branes, compactification

The large extra dimensions model also known as the ADD model proposes that the six hidden dimensions implied by string theory are not rolled up to the Planck length and some (or all) of them are significantly larger which explains the weakness of gravity, it's being diluted by these extra dimensions while the other three fundamental forces are confined to the four-dimensional brane we call reality, retaining their strength. The universal extra dimensions model proposes that one or more of the ADD model's large extra dimensions may be universal, that all four fundamental forces may traverse, potentially allowing for the detection of KK' modes though we have yet to find them.

My question is if "Selective Extra Dimensions" could be a thing. We have dimensions that allow only gravity, we have dimensions that allow all, could we have dimensions that allow using a different set of criteria? Could we have a dimension which allows gravity and electromagnetism in but keeps the nuclear forces out? Could we have a dimension where the strong and weak nuclear forces can enter but EM and gravity can't? Is it possible to have an extra dimension that's inaccessible to all fundamental forces, the literal opposite of a universal extra dimension?

Are these things possible even if they don't describe our universe or is there some fundamental rule that forbids or at least suppresses such things?

Comment: The first thing I'd like to confirm is that you understand that "a dimension" is just a direction in space... That said, in "braneworld" models from string theory, it is natural to have nongravitational forces restricted to the braneworld (since they are mediated by "open strings" whose ends are attached to the brane), but gravity free to propagate in the space beyond the brane (since gravity is mediated by "closed strings", strings that form a loop, which are *not* attached to the brane).

Comment: I understand that dimensions are just directions and not alternate worlds like in pop-scifi but I'm wondering if there's a middle ground between ADD extra dimensions which only allow gravity in and universal extra dimensions which allows all four forces in.